# Разница между ConcurrentBag<T> и List<T>

Tags: c#, .net, многопоточность, коллекции, parallel

Пытаюсь понять разницу между коллекциями `ConcurrentBag<T>` и `List<T>` по этой [статье](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2950955/2948684).

Мне почему-то казалось, что если я буду использовать `List<T>` и в тот момент, когда один поток будет туда что-то записывает и попытается тоже самое сделать другой поток, то выскочит exception, но нет, все работает.

---

### Мой сценарий

Есть сценарий мультипоточной обработки, где в конце своей работы все потоки должны записывать свой результат в **одну** коллекцию:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var results = new List<string>();
        //var results = new ConcurrentBag<string>();

        // STEP 1: Get results.
        Parallel.For(1, 50000, idx =>
        {
            // Some process.
            //...
            results.Add("something");
        });

        // STEP 2: Process results.
        foreach (var result in results)
        {
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Вопрос

Какое преимущество я получаю в случаи использования `ConcurrentBag<T>` вместо `List<T>` в моем случаи?

*И еще такой маленький подвопрос: `results`, его правильно называть **разделяемым** ресурсом*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Мне почему-то казалось, что если я буду использовать List и в тот момент, когда один поток будет туда что-то записывает и попытается тоже самое сделать другой поток, то выскочит exception

Проблема может возникнуть, а может и не возникнуть. Это и называется потоконебезопасная коллекция - когда проблема потенциально может быть. Сегодня работает, завтра упадет - так как нет гарантии, что при параллельной работе 2 потока не попытаются писать одновременно в список.

То, что список у вас внутри `Parallel.For` ещё не гарантирует параллельного доступа. Параллельный доступ - это когда в одну и ту же единицу времени 2 или более потока пытаются работать со списком. В вашем случае при первом, втором, третем запусках такого может и не случиться, но на 99 запуске код упадет.

> мультипоточной обработки

Многопоточной

> Какое преимущество я получаю в случаи использования ConcurrentBag вместо List

В случае выбора `ConcurrentBag<T>` вы получаете гарантию, что ваш код не упадет в многопоточной работе. При работе с `List<T>` никаких гарантий нет, нет даже гарантий от потери данных, не то, чтобы от исключений. Повторю - даже один и тот же многопоточный код может в 99 случаях сработать и в 1 случае упасть при работе с потоконебезопасными коллекциями.

> results, его правильно называть разделяемым ресурсом?

Поскольку потоки его разделяют, то да

В конкретно вашем коде лично я не вижу смысла в разделении ресурса, гораздо проще написать так:

```
var results = Enumerable
        .Range(1, 50000)
        .AsParallel()
        .Select(x=> /*....*/)
        .ToList();

foreach (var result in results)
{
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Мне почему-то казалось, что если я буду использовать List и в тот момент, когда один поток будет туда что-то записывает и попытается тоже самое сделать другой поток, то выскочит exception, но нет, все работает.

`List<T>` не является потокобезопасным. Это означает, что он вообще не предпринимает никаких действий для защиты данных при доступе из разных потоков. Ни блокировок, ни даже *проверок* на одновременный доступ.

Исключения вы не получите, но и гарантии целостности данных - тоже. Используйте `ConcurrentBag<T>`

Comment: На самом деле исключение можно получить, надо просто побольше потоков запустить параллельно, которые бы добавляли записи в список. У меня вот это `Enumerable.Range(1, 50000).AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(16).Select(x => { results.Add("sample"); return 1;}).ToList();` падает в 1 случае из 3 с `Index was outside the bounds of the array.`

Comment: @tym32167 ну да, можно получить, а можно и не получить, гарантий же нет :). это уже следствие повреждения данных, а не следствие защиты от многопоточного доступа, как ожидал топикастер

Comment: ну я написал только потому что увидел `Исключения вы не получите`, а так с вашим ответом согласен конечно.