# использование ConcurentBag при работе с БД

Tags: c#, коллекции, concurrency

Как можно использовать ConcurrentBag  при работе с БД? и в каких случаях это нужно. Большинство примеров рассмотрены с добавлением string/int значений. К коллекции применяются Linq-запросы,  коллекция является неупорядоченной.
Вопрос, который меня интересует:
1) можно ли реализовать CRUD-операции при помощи ConcurrentBag.(если можно то какой-нибудь пример или ссылку).
Смотрел пост [Разница между ConcurrentBag<T> и List<T>](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/854117/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-concurrentbagt-%d0%b8-listt)

Comment: `Как можно использовать ConcurrentBag при работе с БД?` зачем?

Comment: Любые конкуррентные коллекции используются при работе в нескольких потоках. Если вы обращаетесь к СУБД из двух или более потоков и пишете в одну и ту же коллекцию, то эта коллекция должна быть потокобезопасной.